# EFA: variables load on different components as hypothesis

Tags: mathematical-statistics, factor-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I am doing undegrad thesis sand I stumble on some major problems when doing factors analysis:

My research topic is to **compare the attitude of people towards 2 types of products** (namely A and B).

My naive original plan was to **create then compare 2 homogenous SEM models** for each type of products and the proposed model is based on prior researches as well as my own rationale, so I guess I would have to perform EFA on one part of the data and the CFA and SEM for the rest (N=150).

However, when doing EFA, the **variables loading in unwanted way and for each type of product, each set of data has a different pattern**, thus, it is impossible to carry out my plan.

Now, I am thinking of merging the answers for 2 types of products into 1, since I have 2 set of similar questions asking the same aspects but of different objects (A or B). Additionally, there would be another column to distinguish 1-for product A and 0-for product B.

**Pro:**
With an unified poll of data, I will only need to make one model.

**Cons:**
I am not sure yet how to make the comparison if doing so.

I cannot tell which 2 opinions come from whom (which I don't think necessary).

And, instead of having N =150, it would be N=300, I don't know whether this will lead to false statistical results.

SO...

**1. CAN I SKIP DOING EFA and jump on CFA right away?**

**2. If not, will my solution of merging fix my problem?**

**3. If not gain, what else can I do?**

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Merging the data (N=300) looks a better way. So you can build a structural model to regress attitude on product type (a dummy variable, or a single-item construct). This allows you to easily explain the difference in attitude towards different product types.

For your questions: if the measurement items have been widely used before, doing CFA should be fine. If the items are self-developed, you have to do EFA.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have had a second thought on the merging solution, now that I find it problematic since when I merge 2 columns of data into 1, the combine column would not carry any particular meaning. Like if one person think the quality of product A is 5  and B is 1 then we cannot say the quality of A or B is 3... so I think I have no choice but to skip doing EFA?!

Comment: So you used a within subject design. This makes the SEM more complicated. Even the sequence of products A and B might matter. A simple way is to do CFA or EFA for each product, then calculate the mean of all attitude items for each product after CFA/EFA. Then conduct an ANOVA with repeated measures to test the difference in attitude towards A and B.